# How to fill data from a column in database to combobox in c# (using Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I want to fill data (station name) in `Station` column of `Testlog` table in database to combobox to select once query. My code is below but it does not work.

Please help to let me know how to?

```
private void FillComboBox()
{
    ACS_EEEntities dbContext = new ACS_EEEntities();
    comboBoxStationTestLog.DataSource = dbContext.TestLogs.OrderBy(c => c.Station).ToList().Select(c => new { Station = c.Station }).ToList();
    comboBoxStationTestLog.ValueMember = "";
    comboBoxStationTestLog.DisplayMember = "Station";
    comboBoxStationTestLog.SelectedValue = "";
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: If you are using it in web form application you need to call databind method of combobox